# How can I prove that there is a bijective function?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be a nonempty set. Prove that there is a bijective function

$$ F \colon \{ \text{Equivalence relations on } A\} \rightarrow \{\text{Partitions of }A\}. $$

I am completely lost on where to proceed with this question.

Comment: If you have an equivalence relation on $A$, can you not view that as a partitioning of $A$, where $x$ and $y$ are in the same partition iff $x \sim y$?  If you have a partitioning of $A$, can you likewise not view that as an equivalence relation on $A$?

Comment: well, if you have an equivalence relationship can you partition the set so that all the elements in a partition are equivalent?  On the other hand If you partition the set can you define an equivalence relation where elements are equivalent iff they are in the same partition?  If you can do both these things you are basically done.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720553/i-dont-understand-equivalence-relations/720564#720564

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31656/every-equivalence-relation-on-a-set-s-defines-a-corresponding-partition-and-v.

Answer (score 2):

Given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$, the equivalence class of an element $a \in A$ is defined by $[a] := \{ b \in A \, | a \, \sim \, b \}$. Check using the definition that given $a,b \in A$ we have either $[a] = [b]$ or $[a] \cap [b] = \emptyset$ and thus $A = \bigcup_{a \in A} [a]$ is a partition of $A$ into disjoint non-empty subsets.

In the other direction, given a partition $A = \bigcup A_i$, show that you can define an equivalence relation whose equivalence classes are precisely the subsets $A_i$. You will need to check that the binary relation you define satisfies the properties of an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalence relation $R$ on $A$, is one which is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

$R\subseteq A\times A $ where

- $\forall a\in A:\big( (a,a)\in R\big)$,
- $\forall a\in A,\forall b \in A : \big((a,b)\in R\to (b,a)\in R\big)$,
- $\forall a\in A,\forall b\in A,\forall c\in A:\Big(\big( (a,b)\in R\wedge (b,c)\in R\big) \to (a,c)\in R\Big)$

A partition $P$ of $A$ is a set of non-empty subsets of $A$ where every element of $A$ occurs in one and only one of the subsets.

$P\subseteq \mathcal P(A)$ where $\forall a\in A \exists B\in P, \forall C\in P:\Big(x\in B\wedge \big(x\in C\to B=C\big)\Big)$

In short, show that you can map any partition $P$ of $A$, to an equivalence relation $R$, with a one to one correspondence.

---

> Hint 1: Consider the relation: "$x$ is in the same partition subset as $y$". That is: $(x,y)\in R \iff \exists B\in P \big(x\in B\wedge y\in B\big)$   Is this an equivalence relation?

---

> Hint 2: Consider the definition of equivalence class $[x]= \{y: (x,y)\in R\}$   Do the sets of equivalence classes of the elements of $A$ form a partition?